# Magnitude of charge and mass from cloud chamber

Tags: nuclear-physics

I was reading the anderson original article on the discovery of the positron, but I can’t figure out how he estimated the charge and mass. The paper : https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.43.491

Comment: Duplicate - [How can a charge of a particle be determined through its cloud chamber photograph.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359954/how-can-a-charge-of-a-particle-be-determined-through-its-cloud-chamber-photograph)

Answer (score 0):

through an external magnetic field, the charged symbols and the charge-mass ratio can be known.